# Formatted phone number in Call Alert. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string-formatting

I have a problem. I am trying to create call by phone number function. But I need to have a phone number in the format (###)###-#### at standard iOS alert. And for some reason, this function gives different results on different screens. How to change this?

```
if let phoneCallURL:URL = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
    if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: {success in
                print("Open tel: \(success)")
            })
        } else {
            let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(phoneCallURL)
            print("Open: \(success)")
        }
    }
}
```

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Update: 
I tried use formatted strings, but at first page I get unformatted phone number, and at second page I get phone number with this format: #(##) ### ## ##. Always. No matter I use formatted or unformatted phone number.
It seems to me what must be some kind of extension for managing the telephone label in the system alert.

Comment: You may want to use this lib: https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit. It maybe heavy, but if you want all you numbers with standardised format using that lib would be the easiest way to do so.

Comment: may performing url encoding can solve your issue :)

Comment: @user28434 no. this lib uses for textFields. But I need use formatted phone number in label at system iOS alert. It's different.

Comment: @ИльяЗубенко, what? It parses strings, and outputs to strings. It doesn't matter where you gonna use those strings.

Comment: @user28434 It's don't works. I tried use formatted strings, but at first page I always get unformatted phone number, but at second page I always get phone number with this format: #(##) ### ## ##. Always. No matter I use formatted or unformatted phone number.